# Use drupal_add_js before drupal_goto

Tags: php, javascript, drupal, drupal-6

In my Drupal site, I need to redirect the user to a certain page, and then have som javascript code execute once the page is loaded (in order to add a modal dialog on top of the page). After doing some reading, I tried this in my module file:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/scripts.js', 'module');
drupal_goto('path/to/redirect');
```

And then in my javascript file (scripts.js):

```
Drupal.behaviors.mymodule_behaviour = function (context) 
{
  // do some fancy stuff
};
```

This doesn't work, because the javascript is removed from the page when drupal_goto is run. Is there a way to preserve the javascript and make sure that it is run once the page is loaded?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to include `drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/scripts.js', 'module');` on the page that you're redirecting to, not the page you're redirecting from.

Comment: This is what I'm hoping to avoid. The redirect can be to any page on my site, so I'll have to check for the presence of a $_GET variable on each page load and then add the Javascript behaviour if it's there. Messier, but at least it would work.

Comment: Can't really think of any other way at the moment. Add it to page.tpl.php or something to avoid adding it in every single file.

Comment: I'm thinking hook_init instead, cause it's intimately tied to one of my custom modules.

Comment: Seems to be the lesser of all evils.

Comment: Needs to be loaded before the page.tpl.php if you want to take advantage of aggregation.

Comment: Be careful using hook_init(), it gets executed on every single page request if your module is enabled, regardless of whether that page has anything to do with the module. See my answer below. It is better to build any addition of CSS/JavaScript into your menu callback.

Answer (score 2):

Why not make a special path in hook_menu that adds the JS and then redirect to that path from the spot in your code where you know you need the JS added.

Something like this in your hook_menu:

```
$menu['path/to/redirect/JS'] = array(
 'page callback'  => 'my_callback',
 'page arguments' => array(TRUE), // this will pass TRUE as param 1 to the callback
);

$menu['path/to/redirect'] = array(
 'page callback'  => 'my_callback',
 'page arguments' => array(FALSE),
);
```

...

```
function my_callback($add_JS = FALSE) { // $add_JS will be set to TRUE
 if ($add_JS) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/scripts.js', 'module');
 }
}
```

...

When you want the JS added:

drupal_goto('path/to/redirect/JS');

That way you don't need a special page callback or a GET variable, just a special path that looks nice and clean.

Comment: This was a very neat and clean way! Unfortunately I can't use it: I might have to add JS to _any_ page, so I would have to register an extra path for every menu path on the site. But this is going into my bag of tricks - I can see a lot of uses down the road for this technique. Thanks!

Comment: Then I think maybe going with a $_GET variable is your best bet. You could then do a quick check on every single page for the $_GET variable by putting a quick if (isset($_GET['add_JS'])) {} conditional into a hook_init

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up doing, and it worked fine. Again, thanks for your help.